# Oracle MERGE statement in H2 database

Tags: sql, h2, sql-merge

We started to use the H2 in memory database for automated testing. We use Oracle for our production & dev environments. So the idea is to duplicate the table structure in H2 test-database as it is in our Oracle dev-database.

The Oracle SQL statements include MERGE statements and use alias for table names and USING in the query.

How can I modify this query dynamically to be compatible with H2 in a way that it does not alter the existing query in the dev environment?

Example of the Oracle SQL, to be made compatible with H2,

```
MERGE INTO TABLE T1
USING ( SELECT ....
        ...........
        FROM DUAL) T2
```

(T1 & T2 are the alias for the table)

Comment: Your project has chosen a different flavour of database, one with a different SQL drammar, for automated testing?  Fnord.  If you have to rewrite your application so that your automated tests runs what have your tests proved?

Comment: we choose H2, because it can run a in-memory database which is very fast.

Comment: Yes but if it can't run the SQL grammar you use in Dev and Production it doesn't matter how fast the tests run, they're irrelevant.

Comment: I see no point why this question is downvoted - it IS the feature of H2 to emulate Oracle statement syntax ('MODE=Oracle') and it IS a common and good practice in industry to run quick integration tests on in-memory databases.

Answer (score 12):

The [MERGE statement in H2](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge) has a slightly different, simpler syntax:

```
MERGE INTO TEST(ID, NAME) KEY(ID)
SELECT 1, 'Hello' FROM DUAL
```

I guess you would have to write two statements, one for H2, and one for Oracle. The `SELECT` part would be the same however. [The Oracle MERGE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) would be longer, I believe it would be:

```
MERGE INTO TEST T
USING (SELECT 1 ID, 'Hello' NAME FROM DUAL) D
ON (T.ID = D.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET T.NAME = D.NAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (B.ID, B.NAME) VALUES (D.ID, D.NAME);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, as per the syntax above does that mean, I would not be able to use an alias name for the query in H2?

Comment: Yes, but it's not the alias name. The whole syntax of the statement is different.

Answer (score 9):

I am from 2019. H2 supports standard "MERGE INTO ... USING ... WHEN ...".
[Documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#merge_using)

Answer (score 7):

Standard SQL merge syntax support is currently on [the roadmap](http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html) of H2.

> - Support standard MERGE statement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29

However, in some simplistic cases you can use *INSERT ... SELECT + WHERE NOT EXISTS*
For example to insert only if the record does not exist

```
INSERT INTO T1(K1, V2, V3) 
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE
K1 = 1 AND V2 = 2 AND V3 = 3);
```

This construction works both in Oracle and in H2 (at least in MODE=Oracle), so you don't have to have separate SQL inserts for tests and prod.